# Justifying Mutually Independent Events Formula

Tags: probability

Let $A,B$ be two non-zero (for simplicity's sake) probability events. Intuitively, $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A|B) = P(A)$ (which is equivalent to $P(B|A) = P(B)$). It follows that an alternative definition of independence is $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

But how can we relate the extended version of this 'alternative' definition to the intuitive concept? I.e. what does $P(A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_n) = P(A_1)\dots P(A_n)$ mean? My two ideas were that it meant

(1) $P(A_i |\bigcap_{j} A_j$ for $j \neq i)$ = $P(A_i)$

(2) $P(A_i |\bigcup_{j} A_j$ for $j \neq i)$ = $P(A_i)$

But I've had trouble proving equivalence with either

Comment: I don't think $(2)$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the first one: 
$P(A_i|\bigcap_{j\ne i} A_j)=\frac{P(\bigcap_j A_j)}{P(\bigcap_{j\ne i} A_j)}=\frac{\prod_j P(A_j)}{\prod_{j\ne i} P(A_j)}=P(A_i).$
The second one is wrong. For instance take the two fold dice throw and the following events

$A_1$={first throw is a "3"}

$A_2$={second throw is a "3"}

$A_3$={the sum of spots is  $\le$4}.

Then we get that $P(A_1)=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(A_2)=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(A_3)=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(A_1\cap A_2)=\frac{1}{36}$, $P(A_1\cap A_3)=\frac{1}{36}$ and $P(A_2\cap A_3)=\frac{1}{36}$. Hence $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ are independent. But now we get that $P(A_1|A_2\cup A_3)=\frac{P(A_1\cap (A_2\cup A_3))}{P(A_2\cup A_3)}=\frac{\frac{2}{36}}{\frac{11}{36}}=\frac{2}{11}\ne \frac{1}{6}=P(A_1)$.